# How to create a custom mongoose error handler that throws an error but doesn't crash my web server

Tags: express, mongoose

I created a mongoose schema and added a method but I want to throw a custom error like the castErrors and validationErrors that mongoose throws. I also have a error handler for errors like the ones listed above I don't know how to throw the error, please help me.

I tried throwing an error but it crashed my server rather than get caught by error handler.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.